# Python: use odeint to solve second-order linear differential equation

Tags: python, math, differential-equations

I have two differential equations like this:

1. `al=arctan(ri')`
2. `ri''=(vz-C_alz(ri,al))*(1+ri' **2)/C_aln(ri,al)`

The initial value is: `ri(l=0)=2.5, ri'(l=0)=0`

`vz` is a function about l and `C_alz`, `C_aln` are two functions about `ri` and `al`. These 3 complex mathematical expressions are calculated through the code 1, the results are correct and the trajectory of `ri` can be used as the reference to the result of code 2 .

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Fri Dec 18 14:41:07 2015
@author: marswang
code 1
"""

from numpy.linalg import inv
from sympy import sqrt, sin, cos, tan, atan, diff
from numpy import array
import sympy as sp
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
def r_trajektor (L,R):  
    B= np.array([[1, L[0], L[0]**2,L[0]**3 ], [0, 1, 2*L[0], 3*L[0]**2], [1, L[1], L[1]**2, L[1]**3], [0, 1, 2*L[1], 3*L[1]**2]])
    X= np.array([[R[0]], [0], [R[1]], [0]])
    A=np.dot(inv(B), X)
    return A    

a=7.6
rh_s=2420                          
rh_m=2285                          
the_0=11                           
Rc=49                              
vc= 0                             
vp=10

# two points in the r-trajektory and 1. derivative:
# point1 l0=0,r(l0)=2.5 and r'(l0)=0 
# point2 l1=36,r(l1)=22.5 and r'(l1)=0
L= array([[0], [36]])
R= array([[2.5], [22.5]])
# A symbolic derivation expression of vg
ri=sp.Symbol('ri') 
al=sp.Symbol('al')
l=sp.Symbol('l')  
A=r_trajektor(L,R)
# convert 'list' to 'float'
rir=float(A[0])+float(A[1])*l+float(A[2])*l**2+float(A[3])*l**3
dri=diff(rir,l)
alr=atan(diff(rir,l))
dal=diff(alr,l)
hi=a*sqrt((1-sin(the_0+al))/(1+a/(sqrt(2)*ri)))
hir=hi.subs([(al,alr),(ri,rir)])
C_aln=(1-ri**2/(Rc**2))*diff(hi,al)+(a**2)*ri/(Rc**2)*sin(the_0+al)
print C_aln
C_alz=1-(rh_s*ri**2)/(rh_m*Rc**2)+((1-(ri**2)/(Rc**2))*diff(hi,ri)-2*ri*hi/(Rc**2)-(a**2)/(Rc**2)*cos(the_0+al))*tan(al)
print C_alz
vg=((vp-vc)/(diff(al,l)*C_aln+C_alz)).subs([(al,alr),(ri,rir)])
vz=10/vg
print vz


# the function has to be worked with the arrays from numpy too.
# Thus have to lambdify the expression

l_val = np.linspace(0.0,36.0,100.0)

fr=sp.lambdify(l,rir,"numpy")
r_val=fr(l_val)
## plot
pl.figure(figsize=(10,10),dpi=98)
p1 =pl.subplot(2, 1, 1)
p1.plot(l_val,r_val,"g-",label="ri",)
p1.axis([0.0, 40.0,0.0,25.0])
p1.set_ylabel("ri in mm",fontsize=14)
p1.set_xlabel("l in mm",fontsize=14)
p1.legend(loc=4)
```

Now I want to solve these two differential equations and use code 2 to get the the graphic (trajectory) of `ri` in relation to `l` from the calculated `vz` of code 1 reversely.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Sat Jan 02 13:15:19 2016
@author: marswang
code 2
"""
from sympy import sqrt, sin, cos, tan, atan
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
a=7.6                              
rh_s=2420                          
rh_m=2285                          
the_0=11                           
Rc=49                              
vc= 0                             
vp=10

def func(ri,l):
    vz=((-0.00257201646090535*l**2 + 0.0925925925925926*l + 9.25185853854297e-17)*(-0.00633069554352353*sqrt((-sin(atan(-0.00257201646090535*l**2 + 0.0925925925925926*l + 9.25185853854297e-17) + 11) + 1)/(1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5)))*(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5) + 14.44*sqrt(2)*sqrt((-sin(atan(-0.00257201646090535*l**2 + 0.0925925925925926*l + 9.25185853854297e-17) + 11) + 1)/(1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5)))*(-(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5)**2/2401 + 1)/((1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 +
    0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5))*(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 + 9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5)**2) - 0.0240566430653894*cos(atan(-0.00257201646090535*l**2 + 0.0925925925925926*l + 9.25185853854297e-17) + 11)) - 484*(-0.000857338820301783*l**3 + 0.0462962962962963*l**2 +
    9.25185853854297e-17*l + 2.5)**2/1097257 + 1)    
    ri0=ri[0]
    ri1=ri[1]       
    C_aln=0.0240566430653894*ri0*sin(atan(ri1) + 11) - 3.8*sqrt((-sin(atan(ri1) + 11) + 1)/(1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/ri0))*(-ri0**2/2401 + 1)*cos(atan(ri1) + 11)/(-sin(atan(ri1) + 11) + 1)
    C_alz=-484*ri0**2/1097257 + (-0.00633069554352353*ri0*sqrt((-sin(atan(ri1) + 11) + 1)/(1 +
    3.8*sqrt(2)/ri0)) - 0.0240566430653894*cos(atan(ri1) + 11) + 14.44*sqrt(2)*sqrt((-sin(atan(ri1) + 11) + 1)/(1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/ri0))*(-ri0**2/2401 + 1)/(ri0**2*(1 + 3.8*sqrt(2)/ri0)))*tan(atan(ri1)) + 1    
    ri2=(vz-C_alz)*(1+ri1**2)/C_aln/
    return [ri1, ri2]

init = np.array([2.5, 0.1])
l = np.linspace(0.0,36.0,100.0)
sol=odeint(func, init, l)
pl.plot(l, sol[:,0], color='b')
pl.legend()
pl.xlabel(" l in mm ", fontsize=14)
pl.ylabel(" ri in mm ", fontsize=14)
pl.show()
```

I have checked the expression of `vz`, `C_aln`, `C_alz` several times. Those expressions come directly from code 1. But result of code 2 is incorrect and what I get is always different from the reference. 
The reference result of `ri` should be like the first graphic:

[image]

but the calculated result of 'ri' from code 2 is like this:

[image]

I am not sure if I had used `odeint` correctly in this situation, what is the reason for this error between these two graphics?

I am new to Python world, any help would be quite appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The ODE function for a system of dimension two and order 1 should return a vector of dimension two.

For an ODE `u''=f(t,u,u')` the ODE function should follow the scheme

```
def odefunc(t,y):
    u , v = y
    # Computations
    return [ v, f(t,u,v) ]
```

Comment: should I edit my return value in code 2 like: `return [ri1, ri2] `and then `pl.plot(l, sol[:,0], color='b')`. then can i get the return value of ri2, which is ri '' ?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the correct way. `odeint` seems to take care of the vectorization, so even returning an implicit list as in `return ri1, ri2` could be sufficient.

Comment: @ LutzL Thanks. I have another question about Odeint. How should i use odeint? i have wroten like this: `init = [2.5, 0.0] <br/> l = np.linspace(0,36,100) </> sol=odeint(func, init, l)`</> I find, maybe i have make a mistake in the Initial conditions, i want to define the ini. condition like ri[0]=2.5, ri ' [0]=0. Is the format correct?</> sol should be a array of ri1 and ri2?

Comment: @LuzL I have tried. The programm runs well. But the result is even more worse.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you have to go back to the mathematics. Could you, either here in the question or on math.se formulate what your forward and backward problems are in more abstract terms? I think they are not exactly inverse to each other.

Comment: @ Luzl. I will edit it in the question. Is the result theoretically through Odeint exact like the real value?